# How to create Page under a page in confluence from jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins, confluence

I am utilizing publish confluence plugin for jenkins. With this plugin artifacts and other files can be uploaded to the confluence page(desired page).But I want to create a folder structure so that i can manage my stuff.I want my structure like this

```
APP
|
|
|----Regression build
|
|
|----Sprint Build
```

When I am trying to achieve this,every time this plugin is creating a new page for example Regression Build as new page and Sprint Build as new page in same directory structure as APP not under it.

my page link is in this format

https://xxx.xxx.com/confluence/display/CA/APP.

so if I am trying to create Regression build under APP it is creating this new page in same directory struture of APP not under APP as subfolder.

Regards

Comment: Same problem here.. :(

Comment: @MichaelWarkentin Sorry did not tried since then.Though i have tried confluence page api but this specific scenario is not solved I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define parentId. More info here [confluence-publisher](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/confluence-publisher/)

```
def parentId = 123456;

stage('Confluence') 
{
  try 
  {
    publishConfluence siteName: 'siteName', pageName: pageName, spaceName: 'spaceKey',
    attachArchivedArtifacts: true,
    parentId: parentId,
    editorList: [
        confluenceAppendPage(generator: confluenceText('TEST')),
    ]

  }      
  catch(e) 
  {
    echo e.getMessage()
  }
```